# Complex datarame filtering python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a **dataframe**. I want it to filter it and reduce certain values to a string. The dataframe looks like this

[image: Dataframeimage]

**Code:**

```
data = [['42.0', 'A'], ['41.0', 'A'], ['43.0', 'B'],['43.0', 'C'], ['41.0', 'B'], ['42.0', 'B']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Number', 'Level'])
```

**I tried this**

```
df.groupby(['Number', 'Level']).size()
```

**Got this output:**

[image: output]

But I am looking to convert that output to a string like this

```
42.0(1A,1B,0C)
41.0(1A,1B,0C)
43.0(0A,1B,1C)
```

Comment: Why is 42.0 before 41.0?

Comment: Why do u expect to be in an order? The data is in that way by nature. They are not index or some unique key btw

Comment: I was following your groupby output which shows a different order than the expected output.

Comment: Yeah that doesnt matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for original order, then add columns names and join together, last create final string in generator comprehension:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Number'], df['Level']).astype(str).reindex(df['Number'].unique())
s = df.add(df.columns.to_series()).agg(','.join, axis=1)
print (s)
Number
42.0    1A,1B,0C
41.0    1A,1B,0C
43.0    0A,1B,1C
dtype: object

out = '\n'.join(f'{k}({v})' for k, v in s.items())
print (out)
42.0(1A,1B,0C)
41.0(1A,1B,0C)
43.0(0A,1B,1C)
```

Similar solution with nested generator for final ouput:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Number'], df['Level']).astype(str).reindex(df['Number'].unique())

cols = df.columns
out = '\n'.join(f"{i}({','.join(map(''.join, zip(x, cols)))})" 
              for i, x in zip(df.index, df.to_numpy()))
print (out)

42.0(1A,1B,0C)
41.0(1A,1B,0C)
43.0(0A,1B,1C)
```

Comment: Thank u but the solution u provide wont work if the data doesnt have any of the category A or B or C. If I remove the C category row from the dataframe it appears like  this
42.0(1A,1B)
41.0(1A,1B)
43.0(0A,1B)
45.0(1A,1B)

I want like this 

42.0(1A,1B,0C)
41.0(1A,1B,0C)
43.0(0A,1B,0C)
45.0(1A,1B,0C)

Even if C is not there I want it to be there. Total number of categories are A,B and C. Sorry if I was not clear in my question

Comment: @qcoder - then change `.reindex(df['Number'].unique())` to `.reindex(['A','B','C'], fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the required columns first.

```
df['res'] = df.index.astype(str) + df['Level']
print( df.groupby(['Number', 'res']).size() )

###Number  res
###41.0    1A     1
###        4B     1
###42.0    0A     1
###        5B     1
###43.0    2B     1
###        3C     1
###dtype: int64
```